# How do I send messages from Win32 application to Java SWT application?

Tags: java, winapi, swt

I do now Win32 application, which is simple system tray icon application. This application should send information by using (SendMessage) function from Win32 API to another application, which is written on Java SWT. Is there any code example available for it?

Comment: Is the Java / SWT application also something you are writing, or is it a 3rd party app you want to hook into with the win32 API?

Answer (score 0):

You can exchange data between applications using sockets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JNI which will allow calls using SendMessage